# Get label of a given dbpedia resource

Tags: php, sparql, dbpedia, easyrdf

For a given Dbpedia Resource, I want to get its Rdfs: label. For example, from `http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Automobile`, I should get `Automobile`,

I tried with easy RDF:

```
$label= new \EasyRdf\Graph;
$re= $label->label('http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Automobile');
var_dump($re)
```

but it gives me null as a result

I tried also with this Sparql request but it gives me null too:

```sql
SELECT ?label WHERE 
{ 
  <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Automobile> rdfs:label ?label.
}
```

Comment: I never used EasyRdf, but on the start page the example code looks different from yours. Why don't you follow this example?

Comment: I followed it, and i executed several sparql requests using easy rdf it works fine just label of a given reseource uri , it does not work, i tried either with a new sparql request as shown in my edited question but it gives me null

Comment: On which endpoint do you run the query? It works for me on the French Dbpedia endpoint: http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: aaah i used the english version, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just eliminate the (fr.) from your query:

```
SELECT ?label WHERE 
{ 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Automobile> rdfs:label ?label.
}
```